# having troubles escaping the Forward slash. I am using the library stringr library

Tags: r

Am working in R and having troubles escaping the forward slash. I am using the `stringr` library. Here is the string I am working with:

```
she/PRP moved/VBD on/IN before/IN she/PRP could/MD be/VB asked/VBN
```

I would like to remove the forward slash and word `/PRP`, to get this result:

```
 she moved on before she could be asked
```

Answer (score 3):

With the power of regular expressions.

Input:

```
str <- "she/PRP moved/VBD on/IN before/IN she/PRP could/MD be/VB asked/VBN"
```

Code:

```
gsub("/\\w+","",str)
```

Output

```
[1] "she moved on before she could be asked"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre Elrico

Comment: You should check this as answer if it solved your problem. Learn more about regex on `www.regex101.com`. Its a must for every scripter/ programmer.